# Trying to trace Iphone

Tags: iphone

I lost my iphone5 a few minutes ago. I have activated my FindmyIphone. But since the phone is off it is not being traced. Also I have a 4 digit passcode installed to unlock the phone. Is it possible that the phone can be misused in this case. Also what is the likelihood of finding it through FindmyIphone and IMEI registration, I have registered on both.

Comment: What iOS version is the phone running?

Answer (score 1):

[From Apple:](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2526)

> If you have already configured the iCloud Find My iPhone service on
>   your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac you can use it to locate your
>   missing device, display a message on its screen, make it play a sound
>   at full volume (even if on mute), remotely lock it, or remotely wipe
>   (erase) it to protect your privacy. Please see the following articles
>   for more information:

The phone is pretty much useless to who ever found it.

*But consider following as first step:
I just found your phone and it is locked and I have no idea to who it belongs, so there is not much I can do to return it. I could go to police station (but who has time to do that).
If you are so kind you would send a message to your phone with your contact information, email or phone number, I would contact you to arrange the return*.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you were running iOS 7, and enabled Find My iPhone, it is worth nothing to the person who found it.  They will be able to wipe it, however they won't be able to activate it unless they have your Apple ID and password.